# shinyStore cannot restore the selected values of the selectizeInput if the choices are depends on another input

Tags: r, shiny, shinystore

In this example (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/shinystore_de/), I have designed a simple app with two `selectizeInput`. The choices of the second `selectizeInput` depends on the selected results of the first `selectizeInput`. My goal is to design an app that uses the `shinyStore` package (https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore) to save the selected values using the local storage. Next time when users open the app using the same web browser, I hope the values remain.

However, the current is not working. In the following example, I first selected `2` for the first `selectizeInput`, and then selected `f` for the second `selectizeInput`.

[image]

I then clicked the `Save` button, copied the URL, and pasted it in a new web browser. The selected values for the first `selectizeInput` is `2` as expected, but the `selectizeInput` did not show `f`.

[image]

My guess is I used `updateSelectizeInput` twice for the second `selectizeInput`, which leads to confusion. Please see my code as follows and let me know if you have any insights.

**Update**

Here is a follow-up question ([shinyStore cannot restore the selected values of the selectizeInput if the choices are depends on another input and server = TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68291327/7669809)) I asked, which uses `server = TRUE` for the `updateSelectizeInput` and the same strategy is not working.

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                     choices = as.character(1:3),
                     selected = "1",
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                       create = TRUE
                     ))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                       label = "Select A Letter",
                       choices = character(0),
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                         create = TRUE
                       )),
        actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                         choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1])
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select1)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select2)
    }
    updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
    updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
  })

  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                           choices = character(0),
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))

      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modification of the `server` script seems to work. I used a separate `observe` call for the two `selectizeInput`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                         choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1])
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select1)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      req(input$Select1)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select2)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$save > 0){
      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                           choices = character(0),
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))

      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
    }
  })
}
```