# shinyStore cannot restore the selected values of the selectizeInput if the choices depend on another input and server = TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, shinystore

This is a follow-up question from this question ([shinyStore cannot restore the selected values of the selectizeInput if the choices are depends on another input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68264817/7669809)) I asked before. I have figured out the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290227/7669809). However, now I realized that my answer is not complete. Please see the following code. This is the same as my previous question and answer, except that I set `server = TRUE` for the first `updateSelectizeInput`, which makes the local storage not working. It would be great if I could use `server = TRUE` because in my real-world example the choices of my `selectizeInput` are a lot.

```
### This script creates an example of the shinystore package

# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                     choices = as.character(1:3),
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                       create = TRUE
                     ))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                       label = "Select A Letter",
                       choices = character(0),
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                         create = TRUE
                       )),
        actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                         choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
                         # Add server = TRUE make the local storage not working
                         server = TRUE)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select1)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      req(input$Select1)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select2)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$save > 0){
      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                           choices = character(0),
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))

      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have to use custom JavaScript or add further dependencies to solve this problem - `input$store` is `shinyStore's` built-in way to retrieve data from the [localStorage object](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and provides us with all needed information on session start (and it is already being used by @www in the example code).

The [session object](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/session.html) in shiny provides the server (among other things) with client side (or browser) information - e.g. `session$clientData$url_search` or of interest here: `session$input$store`.

We have to make sure, that the selection we are trying to set is available in the `choices` when using `updateSelectizeInput` - e.g. something like this:

`updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "myID", selected = 12, choices = 1:10)`

won't work.

Furthermore, we need to use `freezeReactiveValue` to stop triggering other observers downstream after restoring on session start to avoid overwriting the update again.

`freezeReactiveValue` btw. is almost alway applicable when using `update*` functions in shiny. Please see [this related chapter](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#freezing-reactive-inputs) in *Mastering Shiny*.

```
### This script creates an example of the shinystore package

# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                     choices = as.character(1:3),
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                       create = TRUE
                     ))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                       label = "Select A Letter",
                       choices = character(0),
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                         create = TRUE
                       )),
        actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  storeInit <- observeEvent(input$store, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Select1") # required
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Select2") # not required but should be used before calling any update function which isn't intended to trigger further reactives
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1", selected = input$store$Select1)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", selected = input$store$Select2, choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$store$Select1], server = TRUE)
    storeInit$destroy() # destroying observer, as it is only needed once per session
  }, once = TRUE, ignoreInit = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "Select2") # not required but good practice
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                         choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
                         server = TRUE)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observe({
    if (input$save > 0){
      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "Select1") # not required but good practice
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "Select2") # not required but good practice
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                           choices = character(0),
                           options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                             create = TRUE
                           ))
      
      updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
      updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit: comparison of the answers given**

Now that @lz100 is also using `input$store` instead of `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` both answers are approximating each other.
It boils down to the use of a `reactiveVal` in @lz100's updated answer (`once_flag`) and the use of `freezeReactiveValue` in my answer.

I'd like to point out why I think using `freezeReactiveValue` is the cleaner approach:

The **`once_flag`-approach** fires after `input$Select1` is updated (`observeEvent` parameter `ignoreInit = TRUE`) and is indirectly depending on `input$store`. All other observers depending on `input$Select1` are unnecessarily triggered twice (first on init, second on update).

Here is the according reactlog (0.0321s to first idle):

[image: reactlog_once_flag]

Another flaw of the `once_flag`-approach (as it currently stands) is that the `observeEvent` will fire  everytime `input$Select1` is changed, even though no restoring is ongoing (returning `NULL` but wasting resources).

The **`freezeReactiveValue`-approach** is directly listening to changes of `input$store` when first invoking the app (`once = TRUE, ignoreInit = FALSE`) preventing downstream triggers, which is slightly faster (0.0212s to first idle):

[image: reactlog_freezeReactiveValue]

With a growing app these effects may become more relevant regarding the initialization time - accordingly I second the recommendation I linked above to pair update* functions with `freezeReactiveValue`.

Comment: Nice digging, very nice job. However, that fired twice thing existed in the original code. It wasn't my addition to make it fire twice every time. The OP asked how to make `server=TRUE` work, so I tried to make it a short and readable solution, didn't think too much of performance. The cost comes in the `observe ... req(input$Select1)`, we can call the `suspend` method to disable it after the first time, then the cost is gone, and there are other ways to fix it too. Since the OP didn't ask for this, I didn't touch this part. To me, 0.02s is a very acceptable cost.

Comment: @lz100 in my above edit I already tried to emphasize that in this paricular case the speed gain using `freezeReactiveValue` isn't big, but it might pay off later. This is about good programming practice and in this case it is part of one possible way to solve the issue. The primarily difference of our answers using `input$store` vs. custom JS was a bigger thing and led me to post another answer.

Comment: got it, as you said `input$store` vs JS is bigger, so I thought maybe we could solve it by pure JS, lol. See the third post on this thread. No server code is needed. I tested the performance, but I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 7):

#### Simple Solution

One of simplest solutions can be:

just change your `observeEvent(input$Select1, ...` observer to this one

```r
    once_flag <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
    observeEvent(input$Select1, {
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session, inputId = "Select2", server = TRUE,
            choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1], 
            selected = if(once_flag()) input$store$Select2 else NULL
        )
        once_flag(FALSE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

And you are done. How simple it is! Everything is solved in the same `observeEvent`, with only one call of update. The `once_flag` is to make sure setting `Select2` value only one time. Second time and on when you change `Select1`, we don't set the value of `Select2`.

Thanks for the correction from other users like @ismirsehregal, so I can come up with the simple solution above. Since `shinyStore` has provided you this wrapper API directly by `input$store`, you don't need to write the API as I did below, but the workflow and what's behind are the same. If you are interested in how this solution work, continue to read.

### Original answer

#### cause

The biggest problem we want to solve is `server = TRUE`, read the help file we know that `store choices on the server-side, and load the select options dynamically on searching`. That means your client (UI) doesn't know what are the options at the start. HTML5 localstore (what behind shinystore) is a client-side technology, it can only change things that exist at start. If the options are not given when you launch the app, it can't change it. That's why it failed.

#### detailed solution

If the `select2` is updated after/based on `select1`, can we retrieve the value from `shinystore` after we settle `select1` and then assign the value to `select2`?

The answer is no and yes. <strike>No because the original `shinystore` didn't provide you any API for R-Javascript communication to retrieve the values. It only allows to **set**, **not get**</strike> (not true, see comments, but below is helpful to understand how shinystore works). Yes, is because if you understand how html5 localstorage and how Shiny's JS-R communicate, we can write our own API to get the value.

Here is the workflow:

1. app starts, shiny store updates `select1`
2. server detects `select1` updated, update `select2`'s options
3. tell the client to get the value of `select2` and send from JS to R. (In `shinyStore` you can access it by `input$store$xxx` (input ID). Below, I manually write the code out to show you how they return client-side value into `input` value.)
4. get the value in R and update `select2`'s selected choice

Let's see how it works in code:

##### 1-2, R

```r
    observeEvent(input$Select1, {
        # detect 1 changed 
        # send signal to client to get stored 2's value
        session$sendCustomMessage(
            "shinyStore_getvalue",
            list(
                namespace = "shinyStore-ex1",
                key = "Select2"
            )
        )
        # updated 2's choices based on 1
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                             choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
                             server = TRUE)
        
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

How R-JS communicate, [read this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html).

##### 3, JS

```js
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('shinyStore_getvalue', function(data) {
            var val = localStorage.getItem(`${data.namespace}\\${data.key}`);
            if(val === null) return false;
            val = JSON.parse(val);
            if(val.data === undefined) return false;
            Shiny.setInputValue(`shinystore_${data.key}`, val.data);
        });
```

get the queried `shinystore` value and send it to R shiny as an input value that can be directly `observe`. Not explain details here, again, read that link above if you want to know more.

##### 4, R

```r
    observeEvent(input$shinystore_Select2, {
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session, 
            inputId = "Select2", 
            choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
            server = TRUE,
            selected = input$shinystore_Select2
        )
    }, once = TRUE)
```

Add `once` for only setting the value one time.

Full code for the detailed solution

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)
ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
    tags$script(HTML(
        '
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(\'shinyStore_getvalue\', function(data) {
            var val = localStorage.getItem(`${data.namespace}\\\\${data.key}`);
            if(val === null) return false;
            val = JSON.parse(val);
            if(val.data === undefined) return false;
            Shiny.setInputValue(`shinystore_${data.key}`, val.data);
        });
        '
    )),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
            initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
            selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                           choices = as.character(1:3),
                           options = list(
                               placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                               create = TRUE
                           ))
        ),
        mainPanel = mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                               label = "Select A Letter",
                               choices = character(0),
                               options = list(
                                   placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                                   onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                   create = TRUE
                               )),
                actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
                actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    dat <- data.frame(
        Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
        Letter = letters[1:9]
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$Select1, {
        # detect 1 changed 
        # send signal to client to get stored 2's value
        session$sendCustomMessage(
            "shinyStore_getvalue",
            list(
                namespace = "shinyStore-ex1",
                key = "Select2"
            )
        )
        # # updated 2's choices based on 1
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                             choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
                             server = TRUE)
        
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$shinystore_Select2, {
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session, 
            inputId = "Select2", 
            choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
            server = TRUE,
            selected = input$shinystore_Select2
        )
    }, once = TRUE)
    
    observe({
        if (input$save <= 0){
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select1)
        }
    })
    
    observe({
        if (input$save <= 0){
            req(input$Select1)
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", selected = isolate(input$store)$Select2)
        }
    })
    
    observe({
        if (input$save > 0){
            updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
            updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
        }
    })
    
    observe({
        if (input$clear > 0){
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                                 options = list(
                                     placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                     create = TRUE
                                 ))
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                                 choices = character(0),
                                 options = list(
                                     placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                     create = TRUE
                                 ))
            updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
            updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: No offense @lz100, you are doing great work for the shiny community - however, I'd like to point out that the localStorage data you are passing to shiny's server function via `Shiny.setInputValue` in your `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` call is redundant. It can be accessed via `input$store`. Accordingly your statement regarding `shinyStore`: *"It only allows to set, not get"* is incorrect.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Good catch. You are right, I read shinyStore exported functions but didn't find a `get` function, so I assumed there wasn't. Usually when you design a `set` function then you want to pair it with a `get` function, but they did it with a different way. Anyway, thanks for this and I updated the answer and managed to do everything within the same `observeEvent`!

Comment: Thanks, I know, but this is different. I call it partial `once`. We need the update event to run repeatedly, but the `selected` argument runs only one time. We still need this update event later to update `Select2` when users change `Select1`. Try my code you will see what is "partial" once.

Answer (score 1):

##### Javascript solution

The original answer is long enough, I don't want to add more stuff to there. As mentioned in the comments, the previous two answers are using `input$store`. Here, I provide you with a **pure** Javascript solution. Yes, no server code is edition is needed. Here is the code, read inline comments to understand how it works.

```js
// get shinyStore value
function getStore(namespace, key) {
    var val = localStorage.getItem(`${namespace}\\${key}`);
    if(val === null) return false;
    val = JSON.parse(val);
    if(val.data === undefined) return false;
    return val.data;
}

$(function(){
    var s1 = $('#Select1');
    var s2 = $('#Select2');
    var s1Stored = getStore('shinyStore-ex1', 'Select1');
    var s2Stored = getStore('shinyStore-ex1', 'Select2');
    // If select1 is set we continue, otherwise stop
    if(s1Stored !== false) {
        // Listen to shiny select1 init event
        // Here we use `one` listener to make sure it only runs one time
        s1.one('shiny:bound', function(){
            var s1Binding = s1.data('shiny-input-binding');
            // set select1 value to our stored value
            s1Binding.setValue(this, s1Stored);
        });
    }
    // if select2 is stored we, continue to set select2
    if(s2Stored !== false) {
        // Here we use 2 `one` nested change listener, select2 is a little trickier. 
        // the first time value change is due Shiny init. The second time is we changed select1 and serverside
        // sends new choices to client, caused the default to set. 
        // We can change to the stored value afterwards,
        // so we set the value exactly after the second time.
        s2.one('change', function(){
            s2.one('change', function(){
                var s2Binding = s2.data('shiny-input-binding');
                s2Binding.setValue(s2.get(0), s2Stored);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of adding code to the server, we remove 2 redundant observers. Here is the full code.

```r
### This script creates an example of the shinystore package

# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)
myscript <- tags$script(HTML("
function getStore(namespace, key) {
    var val = localStorage.getItem(`${namespace}\\\\${key}`);
    if(val === null) return false;
    val = JSON.parse(val);
    if(val.data === undefined) return false;
    return val.data;
}

$(function(){
    var s1 = $('#Select1');
    var s2 = $('#Select2');
    var s1Stored = getStore('shinyStore-ex1', 'Select1');
    var s2Stored = getStore('shinyStore-ex1', 'Select2');
    if(s1Stored !== false) {
        s1.one('shiny:bound', function(){
            var s1Binding = s1.data('shiny-input-binding');
            s1Binding.setValue(this, s1Stored);
        });
    }
    if(s2Stored !== false) {
        s2.one('change', function(){
            s2.one('change', function(){
                var s2Binding = s2.data('shiny-input-binding');
                s2Binding.setValue(s2.get(0), s2Stored);
            });
        });
    }
});

"))

ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
            initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
            selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                           choices = as.character(1:3),
                           options = list(
                               placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                               create = TRUE
                           ))
        ),
        mainPanel = mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                               label = "Select A Letter",
                               choices = character(0),
                               options = list(
                                   placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                                   onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                   create = TRUE
                               )),
                actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
                actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
            )
        )
    ),
    myscript
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    dat <- data.frame(
        Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
        Letter = letters[1:9]
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$Select1, {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                             choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% isolate(input$Select1)],
                             # Add server = TRUE make the local storage not working
                             server = T)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observe({
        if (input$save > 0){
            updateStore(session, name = "Select1", isolate(input$Select1))
            updateStore(session, name = "Select2", isolate(input$Select2))
        }
    })
    
    observe({
        if (input$clear > 0){
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select1",
                                 options = list(
                                     placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                     create = TRUE
                                 ))
            updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2",
                                 choices = character(0),
                                 options = list(
                                     placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                                     create = TRUE
                                 ))
            
            updateStore(session, name = "Select1", NULL)
            updateStore(session, name = "Select2", NULL)
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In terms of performance, there is no noticeable difference with the previous 2, but like mentioned, may be useful later with some heavy app. The good thing is this code runs on the client side. How fast it runs mainly depends on your users' computers, which reduces your server burden, just a little, but a little for each user can sum up to be a big number. Imagine thousands of people are using the app simultaneously. The bad thing is you need to learn JS, not very friendly for beginners.

So, it all depends on your real-world needs. If you want some quick and short solution, use my first post; If you care about performance but don't want to use JS, use @ismirsehregal post; If you have a heavy app and want to have a lot of users, this JS solution maybe better.